# Most efficient C++ data structure for iterating when order doesn't matter?

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

I want to keep a list of objects so that I can iterate over them and notify each of them of an event by iterating over each of them. I don't care what order they get notified in, I just need the iteration and method-calling on these objects to happen as quickly as possible.

What is the most efficient (C++ standard library) data structure for this sort of feature?

Comment: Likely `std::vector`

Comment: It depends on how you iterate, how much you know upfront (for example data structure size), and many other things. In general, go for `std::array` or a plain C array if you know the size upfront, or `std::vector` otherwise. If you *measure* (do not base it off a theory) an issue with that, then it's worth looking at the others :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "most efficient" in this world.

Comment: Unless the action that each object is to take upon notification is absolutely trivial, the amount of time spent iterating will be negligible compared to the amount of time spent processing the notifications. So picking a data structure based on how fast you can iterate over it in this case is probably a mistake. It's hard to beat a plain old-fashioned array for raw access speed.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you find yourself asking a question like "which way is faster, X or Y?", or "what's the fastest X?", there is only one real answer:

**Benchmark it.**

If you're at the stage where you're not sure and just have to pick one, here's a rule of thumb unless measurements dictate otherwise:

- Is it fixed size? Use `std::array` or a plain C array.
- Is it always going to be within some fixed bounds? Use `std::array` or a plain C array.
- Otherwise, use `std::vector`.

Note that if you find out the size you need at runtime, you can use `std::vector::reserve` to potentially reduce the number of memory allocations needed, which can lead to a performance boost. Of course, you'd measure it just to be sure ;)

---

<sub>Also note that 'efficient' can mean different things depending on your domain. Using less RAM, for example, might be better for some, even at the cost of CPU cycles.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Efficient iteration is sensitive to [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss). This means that the best you can do (in a general case, excluding multithreading/[false cache sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) issue) is to keep your items in continuous memory region, and to iterate over them in their memory order. Continuous memory is provided by c-array, `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Now, about calling a method of each item. If you store your items as (any) pointer means that items itself are somewhere else in your RAM, probably dynamically allocated and so can be quite scattered over the memory. So calling a method on each item can involve cache miss which can be quite costly. So it's worth to consider to store your items by values.

And yeah, as usual, don't trust me but your profiler

Answer (score 0):

If it is fixed size or has a limited max size you could use a C-Array.

If you need a dynamic approach you could use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

I don't know exactly how `std::vector` is implemented but as far as i know `std::list` is implemented as double linked list and therefore perform iterating to the next element in O(1) time resulting in total iteration in O(n) time.